# How to decode utf8 data into simple string in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am facing issue while decoding a utf8 string into simple string which is i am getting from android. String contains both words and emoji's.
For Example:
I am storing this type of data in mysql db `\u263A\uD83D\uDE22\uD83D\uDC4D\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDC90`. But fail to decode in readable format.

Comment: How javascript is related to this?

Comment: If there is any solution using javascript. i can implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you treat it as JSON object, it will work:

```
<?php
    $input = '{"key":"\u263A\uD83D\uDE22\uD83D\uDC4D\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDC90"}';
    $output = json_decode($input, true);
    print $output["key"];
```

Output:

> ☺

Comment: @Shahrukh Accept the answer plz.

Comment: i am facing issue while i m decoding multiline message.

Comment: @Shahrukh Put the text you are trying to decode into the comment, and I'll look.

Comment: $input = '{"key":"hello  to  you"}';
    $output = json_decode($input, true);
    print  $output["key"];
if sentence in a single line it is working fine

Comment: if sentence in a mulit line then it is printing blank.
$input = '{"key":"hello
 to 
you"}'; $output = json_decode($input, true); print $output["key"];

Comment: in stack overflow i am not able to to write mulitline sentence. please understand my issue

Comment: @Shahrukh I see no problems with the newline character: $input = '{"key":"hello\nto you"}'; $output = json_decode($input, true); print $output["key"];

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use decodeURIComponent for that, like this:

```
function decode(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}
```